# android chat application - ListView vs ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I'm building a chat application.

Inside my chat messages view i have an Activity which render last 20 messages and add them to a ScrollView programmatically.

It actually works pretty good and fast.

After finishing it I've stop to think and realized that i could have done it more easily (and maybe more efficient) using a ListView.

Is it really true? should i take the effort and change the view to a ListView ?

Comment: Accept the best answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, yeah its more efficient to use a listView because of its properties. And what you did with your scroll view has the same function as a ListView. You're remaking the wheel I think. [Here](http://www.mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/listview-transcript-mode)'s a good example :)

Answer (score 2):

I will say yes for one main reason: `ListView` recycles the Views shown on the screen making it very efficient. Since it'll hold say, 6 or 7 ish Views on a smaller screen, and reuse those, its much more efficient than say your 20 Views taking up memory. As for easier, that can be debatable. But definitely recommend ListView. ScrollView may feel fast, but you also got to think about performance of the device and other apps in general.

Answer (score 0):

I have a chat feature in my app and I use an adapter to inflate the messages into a listview. Below is a sample of my xml layout:

messages.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    <TextView </TextView>
    <ListView </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

message_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout>
      <LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout> 
      <LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout>
      <TextView></TextView>
  <TextView></TextView>
      </LinearLayout>

      <TextView></TextView>
      </LinearLayout>

      <ImageView></ImageView>
      </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
      <TextView></TextView>
      </RelativeLayout>
```

I hope that helps:)

Answer (score 0):

You can scan the android source code and learn how ListView implements.

I think you'll find your answer after that.

ics/framework/base/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java